# Multi Tenant unica base de datos con esquemas separados

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy diseñando una base de datos y gusto la idea de hacerla como dice el titulo, el tema es que la quería hacer en MySQL pero dice que solo se puede implementar en PostgreSQL, me gustaría saber si alguien sabe el porque de esto. Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Quien dice? donde dice? porque dice? que es lo que no podrias implementar en mysql? es una buena pregunta, pero deja como el escenario abierto porque no explicas el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible diseñarla en MySQL, asumo que a lo que te refieres es a un diseño en puente, es decir, una única instalación del MySQL con multiples bases de datos con la misma estructura para tu aplicación. Hasta donde tengo entendido es un asunto de nomenclatura, un esquema en PostgreSQL es lo mismo que una database en en MySQL.

En estos momentos tengo una aplicación en producción con este modelo corriendo en una instalación de MySQL sin ningún problema, el asunto siempre está en lograr que desde la capa de aplicación se realicen las consultas con la conexión adecuanda al esquema adecuado pero si debo aconcejar sobre la administración, un esquema multitenant en puente es más trabajo porque tienes que replicar cada cambio en cada esquema, pero la ventaja es que tienes más control sobre cada cliente así que eso ya depende de los requerimientos de tu aplicación.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es al diseño de MultiTenant en una base de datos unica, con esquemas separados.